# Different converted date from dev to production using Docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I'm using Docker in production environment of my `.NET Core 3.1 C# WebAPI` application.

I configured in `Startup.cs`:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("it-IT");

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

var supportedCultures = new[] { cultureInfo };

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
      DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("it-IT"),
      // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
      SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
      // UI strings that we have localized.
      SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

Calling the API in my local machine with `"it-IT"` culture and converting a date:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("1976-10-30T23:00:00.000Z")
```

Returns the datetime I expected: `"{31/10/1976 01:00:00}"`.

When I deploy in production the date is converted in `"{30/10/1976 23:00:00}"`.

I think the Docker container has a different Culture from local machine or culture is not installed at all.

My Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.101-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
...
```

Also running this code in local machine:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
Log.Warning("Installed Language Info:{0}", ci.Name);
ci = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
Log.Warning("Current UI Language Info: {0}", ci.Name);
ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
Log.Warning("Current Language Info: {0}", ci.Name);
```

I get:

```
[10:06:17 WRN] Installed Language Info:it-IT
[10:06:17 WRN] Current UI Language Info: it-IT
[10:06:17 WRN] Current Language Info: it-IT
```

and in Docker:

```
[10:12:08 WRN] Installed Language Info:
[10:12:08 WRN] Current UI Language Info: it-IT
[10:12:08 WRN] Current Language Info: it-IT
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: As I understand, it is not an issue of culture, because the formatting etc is not the issue. Your problem seems to be the TimeZone. Every machine has a local timezone that is set by the host OS and which you cannot change. The docker server you are running on production has a different time zone.

Comment: You have to change your application to use DateTime.ToUniversalTime where possible to make your application independent of the time zone.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to missing cultures on the base image. Here's an similar issue described with the alpine image - https://andrewlock.net/dotnet-core-docker-and-cultures-solving-culture-issues-porting-a-net-core-app-from-windows-to-linux/

And when time zone is missing, it goes to invariant / UTC.